# Find valid slaveaddresses or number of slaveaddresses in minimalmodbus

Tags: minimalmodbus

The documentation doesn't offer a way to do this and as far as i know a bus is not designed to do this. But maybe there is a kind of answer one can get from the devices without disturbing anything to determine which ones are there?

Answer (score 0):

Searching a lot did not yield any answer besides "try every possible address and see if you get an answer"
Given that professional software also seems to use this aproach, it is probably the only way.